# Short way to apply gensub to all fields in awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

I have this awk command which reads single line xml with different fields. I had to use gensub on all fields one by one.

suppose this is my xml file

```
<users><user><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></user></users>
```

The output i want is

1--2--3

Also i want to use from command line and i would like one liner if possible.
Is there any way to make this command short

```
awk -v FS='><' -v RS="</?user>" '{
    a=gensub(/.*>(.*)<.*/, "\\1",  "g", $1); 
    b=gensub(/.*>(.*)<.*/, "\\1",  "g", $2); 
    c=gensub(/.*>(.*)<.*/, "\\1",  "g", $3); 
    print a"--"b"--"c}' abc.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'<[^>]+>' -v OFS='--' '{print $4, $6, $8}' file
1--2--3
```

If that's not what you want then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input and expected output.

Given the new input format provided in your comments:

```
$ cat file
<users><user><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c><user><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c><user><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></user></users>

$ awk -v RS='</?user>' -F'<[^>]+>' -v OFS='--' 'RT&&(NR>1){print $2, $4, $6}' file
1--2--3
1--2--3
1--2--3
```

The above requires GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT.

Comment: thanks that working but instead of one user i have many users in that xml like<user> ...</user>  multiple these tags

Comment: So? If you're trying to convey that there's some kind of problem, I'm not getting it. If your real input is different enough from your sample input that this works on the sample but not the real then you need to open a new question and post a more realistic sample that demonstrates your problem cases.

Comment: sorry for that my real input is like this `<users><user><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c><user><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c><user><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></user></users>` and i want out put 1--2--3 for each user record in xml file

Comment: Then post a question related to parsing that input and with that as your sample input and expected output. I can't stress enough how important it is for your sample input to represent your real data - all the supporting verbiage is nice but the sample input/output is about 80% of what we go by when coming up with a solution.

Comment: Oh, what the heck - I just updated my answer to show how to deal with input like in your comment. Next time...

Comment: Thanks buddy , i will take care next time

Answer (score 0):

with `awk`

```
awk -v FS="[^[:digit:]]+" -v OFS="--" -v RS="<(/)?user(s)?>" 'NF{print $2,$3,$4}' file
```

Output

```
1--2--3
```

Breakdown

```
FS="[^[:digit:]]+" #matches non-digit string and takes it as FS
OFS="--" #Output FS
RS="<(/)?user(s)?>" # RS for users/user tag
NF{print $2,$3,$4} #print the first 3 digits if any fields are present
```